# How to execute transactions of my Ethereum contract deployed on Rinkeby test client using REST apis?

Tags: solidity, etherscan, rinkeby

I would like to build a UI on top of my ethereum contract and how can I get a use a REST API to execute transactions in my contract ?
which one of Rinkeby etherscan API could be used ?

Comment: Why don't you try to use web3? https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethcontract

Answer (score 0):

have a look at https://cinder.cloud/ethereum-contract-api. In combination with https://arkane.network, you'll have an integration in no time.